# Error in linking gmp while compiling cpabe package from its source code

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, linker, gmp

I ended up spending several hours for compiling cpabe package from its source code in Ubuntu 12.10, with gmp and pbc dependencies. The following error message seemed to be the problem of many people in the Web(even for compiling other packages that required installation of libgmp as a dependency!). Yet, I couldn't find any workable solution there:

```
...
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpbc.so: undefined reference to symbol '__gmpz_init'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '__gmpz_init' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be trivial for some of you, but policy_lang.y is missing a semicolon in line 67, hence the compilation fails with:

```
 policy_lang.y: In function ‘yyparse’:
 policy_lang.y:67:38: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token
 result: policy { final_policy = $1 }
```

It can be fixed by changing line 67 to

```
 result: policy { final_policy = $1; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding lgmp was necessary, but all other used libraries needed to be linked as well. I finally solved the problem by specifying those libraries in the LDFLAGS environment variable while issuing the make command. So, after installation of gmp, pbc, bswabe or any other required dependencies, the compilation steps was as follows:

- ./configure -with-pbc-include=path -with-pbc-lib=path (the paths where pbc.h and libpbc were installed )
- make LDFLAGS="-lgmp -lpbc -lcrypto -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib -lbswabe -lgmp"
- make install

Comment: I tried doing this, I ran into error
gcc -o cpabe-setup setup.o common.o -lgmp -lpbc -lcrypto -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib -lbswabe -lgmp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cpabe-setup] Error 1
How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Mine was a slight variation of MarAlavi's, for linux Mint 16:

- `./configure -with-pbc-include=path -with-pbc-lib=path` (the paths where `pbc.h` and `libpbc` were installed )
- `make LDFLAGS="-lgmp -lpbc -lcrypto -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lglib-2.0 -lbswabe -lgmp"`
- `make install`

Notice the "`-lglib-2.0`".

Answer (score 0):

> try adding it to the linker command line

Did you try adding `-lgmp` to the link command line as the error suggests?